# How to Fetch two keys from a dict using single loop in HTML-template

Tags: python, django-templates

[My HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3laD.png)

the below is the dict sent to the html using render_to_response

{'header_list': ['About Us', 'Disclaimer', 'Locate', 'Order Now', 'Login', 'Register'], 'sidebar_list': ['About Us', 'Disclaimer', 'Locate', 'Order Now', 'Login', 'Register'], 'href_list': ['/admin/', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#']}

```
fp = os.path.join(fp, 'static/appdata/menubar.txt')
with open(fp, 'r') as mb:
    for i, line in enumerate(mb):
        menu_list.append(line)
        hl = ast.literal_eval(menu_list[i])
        head_list.update(hl)
print(head_list, type(head_list))
hl = head_list['href_list']
print(hl)
return render_to_response('header.html', head_list)
```

My HTML Code in header.html

```html
<div id="nav">
                <ul>

                    {% for i1 in  header_list %}

                        <li><a href={{ href_list.1 }}><span>{{ i1 }}</span></a></li>

                    {% endfor %}

                </ul>
            </div>
```

i want to use the tag for href dynamically through the dict list

The Page header looks like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtFQt.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the dict like this 
{'header_list' : [('About Us', '/admin/'), ('Disclaimer','#'), ('Locate','#'), ('Order Now', '#'), ('Login', '#'), ('Register', '#')]}

and the HTML code like the following

```html
{% for i1, i2 in  header_list %}
  <li><a href={{ i2 }}><span>{{ i1 }}</span></a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

In python, you can access value of a key of a dict and list elements in this syntax:

```
my_dict = {'key1':1,'key2':2}
my_dict['key1']
my_list = [1,2,3,4,'hello']
my_list[4]
```

In your example, you're trying to access the 1st element using `href_list.1` which i think should be `href_list[1]`

EDIT:

```
>>> a
[12, 34, 4]
>>> b
[3, 4, 5]
>>> [(a[i],b[i]) for i in range(len(a))]
[(12, 3), (34, 4), (4, 5)]
>>>
```

Now you'll be able to do,

```
for i,j in [(a[i],b[i]) for i in range(len(a))]:
    print('link:{},name:{}'.format(i,j))
```

and you can do the same if your template loop

Comment: yeah i know i am using href_list.1 because i am not able to fetch the href_list which is of the list form in the for loop of the html code.

Comment: In that case your `header_list` should be a list of dicts having name and href, that way it would be easier to implement, otherwise in this case, I've edited my answer,

Comment: as per your comment i have updated my dict which looks like this now {'header_list' : [('About Us', '/admin/'), ('Disclaimer','#'), ('Locate','#'), ('Order Now', '#'), ('Login', '#'), ('Register', '#')]}                                                              what is to be done to get About Us printed and '/admin/' to be its href and similarly for others

Comment: Thanks my Problem is solved by changing the dict to {'header_list' : [('About Us', '/admin/'), ('Disclaimer','#'), ('Locate','#'), ('Order Now', '#'), ('Login', '#'), ('Register', '#')]} and the html code like                                
                    {% for i1, i2 in  header_list %}
                        <li><a href={{ i2 }}><span>{{ i1 }}</span></a></li>
                    {% endfor %}

Comment: If it solves your problem, then please mark the question answered :)